# Need to install some MariaDB/Mysql tools for Python Mysql and having issues with dependancies

Tags: python, mariadb

### Here is the version I'm running.

```
mysqld  Ver 10.5.15-MariaDB-1:10.5.15+maria~focal-log for
debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (mariadb.org binary distribution)
```

--
Attempting to install

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```

And ending up with

```
libmariadbclient-dev : Depends: libmariadb-dev (= 1:10.3.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

installed on the machine is

```
libdbd-mariadb-perl/focal,now 1.11-3ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmariadb-dev-compat/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
libmariadb-dev/unknown,now 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64 [installed]
libmariadb-java/focal 2.5.3-1 all
libmariadb3-compat/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
libmariadb3/unknown,now 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmariadbclient-dev/focal-updates,focal-security 1:10.3.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64
libmariadbclient18/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
libmariadbd-dev/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
libmariadbd19/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
libmysqlclient18/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
maria-doc/focal 1.3.5-4.1build2 all
maria/focal 1.3.5-4.1build2 amd64
mariadb-backup/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:10.5.16+maria~focal]
mariadb-client-10.3/focal-updates,focal-security 1:10.3.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64
mariadb-client-10.5/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:10.5.16+maria~focal]
mariadb-client-core-10.3/focal-updates,focal-security 1:10.3.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64
mariadb-client-core-10.5/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:10.5.16+maria~focal]
mariadb-client/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 all [upgradable from: 1:10.5.16+maria~focal]
mariadb-columnstore-cmapi/unknown 22.08.2 amd64
mariadb-common/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 all [upgradable from: 1:10.5.16+maria~focal]
mariadb-plugin-columnstore/unknown 1:10.5.19-5.6.8+maria~ubu2004 amd64
mariadb-plugin-connect/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
mariadb-plugin-cracklib-password-check/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
mariadb-plugin-gssapi-client/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
mariadb-plugin-gssapi-server/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
mariadb-plugin-mroonga/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
mariadb-plugin-oqgraph/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
mariadb-plugin-rocksdb/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
mariadb-plugin-s3/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
mariadb-plugin-spider/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
mariadb-plugin-tokudb/focal-updates,focal-security 1:10.3.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64
mariadb-server-10.3/focal-updates,focal-security 1:10.3.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64
mariadb-server-10.5/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:10.5.15+maria~focal]
mariadb-server-core-10.3/focal-updates,focal-security 1:10.3.38-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64
mariadb-server-core-10.5/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64 [upgradable from: 1:10.5.15+maria~focal]
mariadb-server/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 all [upgradable from: 1:10.5.15+maria~focal]
mariadb-test-data/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 all
mariadb-test/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 amd64
mysql-common/unknown 1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 all [upgradable from: 1:10.5.15+maria~focal]
odbc-mariadb/focal 3.1.4-1 amd64
```

Comment: I can't be sure, but I'm guessing your trying to install the libmariadbclient-dev virtual package found the focal repo one (10.3) instead of the mariadb 10.5 repo one, which dragged in a lot of 10.3 dependencies.  try deleting all the 10.3 packages (back up your data first just to be safe) and install libmariadb-dev instead (which should find the 10.5 version).

Comment: The order I would try: 1) `# apt-get update --fix-missing` 2)  `# dpkg --configure -a` 3) `# aptitude` - run without parameters, the interactive mode is pretty good

Comment: I am very surprised it is even possible to have mariadb-server-10.3 and mariadb-server-10.5 installed at once.